# Unique Colors for Chart Data

Tags: html, html5

This is likely in the wrong section but I'm curious if there is a good way to select unique and distinct colors for plotting data on charts? My current method is to hard code a set plot limit with color codes predefined. Im sure there is a *random* generator but the colors must be noticeably different for legibility. Are there any resources online that compile lists of codes for uses like this where I could handle this more easily or is there a method I may not be aware of?

I apologize if this is in the wrong section. I am just looking for resources.

Comment: Maybe, pick the smallest [palette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palette_(computing)) that has enough colors for your chart; [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_palettes) speaks mostly larger and larger palettes (in terms of bit count), but you can shrink a palette as well.  See also [list of colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors_(compact)) and [web colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors).

Comment: @ErikEidt thank you for the response. I will definitely look into those. I realized I can also style the plotted data differently so the colors can be the same but the data can still be differentiated.

Comment: One way to tackle this is to work with HSV, rather than RGB colours. By keeping the saturation (S) and brightness (V) constant, you can then change the hue (H) to create a range of complimentary, but distinctive colours for things like charts. There's plenty of resources online that let you play with HSV colours and convert them to RGB if you want to hard code them. Or use an HSV library to generate such colours at runtime.

Comment: You might be interested in [How can I find an optimum set of colors for 10 players?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/46463/10408), see also linked and related questions on that site.

Comment: Maybe this site will help you to find optimum color sets:https://learnui.design/tools/data-color-picker.html